# C++ Qt Do something when an QListWidgetItem from a QListWidget is clicked or selected

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

```
QListWidgetItem* lwi = new QListWidgetItem(text.c_str());
lw->addItem(lwi);
QObject::connect(lwi, &QListWidgetItem::isSelected, &lwi, []() {
    exit(0);
});
```

I want to do something like this, where if an item from the QListWidget is selected or clicked the program will just exit. But this is not the correct syntax and I have no idea how to make it right. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

[`QListWidgetItem::isSelected`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#isSelected) is not a Qt signal.

Most likely, your `QListWidgetItem` will be embedded in a
[`QListWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html). `QListWidget`
provides several [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#signals)
which may fit your needs. E.g.:

```
QListWidgetItem* lwi = new QListWidgetItem(text.c_str());
lw->addItem(lwi);

// Assuming lw is a QListWidget*
QObject::connect(lw, &QListWidget::currentItemChanged,
    [lwi](QListWidgetItem* current, QListWidgetItem* /*previous*/)
    {
        if (current == lwi) std::exit(0);
    });
```

Please also note you don't need to pass the receiver address when [connecting a signal to a lambda](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4) (or a functor, in general).